# How can i merge a bidimensional list using new lines "\n"?

Tags: python, arraylist

I have the output of a maze solver as a bidimensional array and want to give it the format of a real maze, this is my nested for loop that merges the array:

```
for renglon in solucion:
            solucionCompleta = "\n".join(''.join(l) for l in solucion)
            for elemento in renglon:
                mediaSalida = ''.join(''.join(l) for l in renglon)
```

I'm currently using the '\n' to make the jump lines but just gives me an output like this:

```
'#####X#\n#####*#\n####**#\n####*##\n*****##\nR######'
```

This tells me that is joining the arrays in the right way but doesn't at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if I misunderstood but if you want to see the maze printing the string give you a visualisation

```
print('#####X#\n#####*#\n####**#\n####*##\n*****##\nR######')


#####X#
#####*#
####**#
####*##
*****##
R######
```